# Search or Find IO Serialized objects in file with c#

Tags: c#, c++

I am serializing c# objects and appent to file. But so many objects increasing in file. About 20000 object.

```
   public void SerializeObject(string filename, ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize)
   {
      Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
      BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      bFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
      stream.Close();
   }
```

And later I want to get an object from this file. So how can I find it. Is deserializing 20000 object in an array and search by linq make sense? Or is there any practical way?

Programming language not important may be c++ or c#.

Comment: Just use a data base to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any other metadata, deserializing the object is your only option. You won't be able to query the object until you deserialize it, and yes deserializing 20,000 objects will be hard.

But, since YOU serialized it in the first place, YOU could persist some meta data that would make it easier to search in the first place.

For example:

```
Dictionary<string,string> Index = new Dictionary<string,string>();
Index.Add(fileIdentifierThatYouWouldSearchOn,fileName);
```

Then you could serialize the Index. Everytime you persist a new file, also maintain the Index file. Then you can deserialize just the Index, find the filename you want, and load up just that file.

Comment: Perhaps you aren't familiar with DBs at all? Unless you have a reason to store the objects as serialized files, my FIRST inclination would be to store the object as a table in the DB. Then use any ORM that you choose (EntityFramework if you are an MS shop is the default choice these days) to handle hydrating and dehydrating your objects. If you DO have a reason why they need to be serialized to disk, you could still store meta data in the DB and just include the filename and path of the serialized file.